# Можно ли упростить код

Tags: javascript, рефакторинг, чистый-код

Можно ли упростить данный код для более легкого добавления элементов?

```
document.getElementById('exampleInputshema').onkeyup = function () {
    var reg = /[а-яА-ЯёЁ]/g;
    if (this.value.search(reg) !=  -1) {
        this.value  =  this.value.replace(reg, '');
    }
}

document.getElementById('exampleInputrost').onkeyup = function () {
    var reg = /[^0-9]/g;
    if (this.value.search(reg) !=  -1) {
        this.value  =  this.value.replace(reg, '');
    }
}

document.getElementById('exampleInputves').onkeyup = function () {
    var reg = /[^0-9]/g;
    if (this.value.search(reg) !=  -1) {
        this.value  =  this.value.replace(reg, '');
    }
}



// Схема TPF
let docetaxel = 75;
let cisplatin = 100;
let fivephtoruracil = 1000;

//Схема TIP
let paklitaxel = 175;
let iphosfamid = 1000;
let mesna_tip_do = 400;
let mesna_tip_posle = 200;
let cisplatina = 60;

//Схема TIC
let paklitaxel_tic = 175;
let iphosfamid_tic = 1000;
let mesna_tic_do = 400;
let mesna_tic_posle = 200;

//EP
let cisplatin_ep = 80;
let etopozid_ep = 80;

//EC
let etopozid_ec = 100;

//CAV
let ciklofosfamid_cav = 1000;
let doxorubicin_cav = 40;
let vinkristin_cav = 1.4;

//CAE
let ciklofosfamid_cae = 1000;
let doxorubicin_cae = 40;
let etopozid_cae = 50;

//ECF
let epirubicin_ecf = 50;
let cisplatin_ecf = 60;
let fivephtoruracil_ecf = 200;

//EOF
let epirubicin_eof = 50;
let oxaliplatin_eof = 130;
let fivephtoruracil_eof = 200;

//EOX
let epirubicin_eox = 50;
let oxaliplatin_eox = 130;
let kapecitabin_eox = 625;

//ECX
let epirubicin_ecx = 50;
let cisplatin_ecx = 60;
let kapecitabin_ecx = 625;

//XELOX
let oxaliplatin_xelox = 130;
let kapecitabin_xelox = 1000;

//DCF
let docetaksel_dcf = 75;
let cisplatin_dcf = 75;
let fivephtoruracil_dcf = 750;

//CF
let cisplatin_cf = 100;
let fivephtoruracil_cf = 1000;

//MAYO
let fivephtoruracil_mayo = 425;
let leikovorin_mayo = 20;

//ROSWELL
let fivephtoruracil_roswell = 500;
let leikovorin_roswell = 500;

//FOLFOX4
let fivephtoruracil_folfox4_do = 400;
let fivephtoruracil_folfox4_posle = 600;
let leikovorin_folfox4 = 200;
let oxaliplatin_folfox4 = 85;

//FOLFOX6
let fivephtoruracil_folfox6_do = 400;
let fivephtoruracil_folfox6_posle = 2400;
let leikovorin_folfox6 = 400;
let oxaliplatin_folfox6 = 85;

//MFOLFOX7
let fivephtoruracil_mfolfox7 = 3000;
let leikovorin_mfolfox7 = 200;
let oxaliplatin_mfolfox7 = 100;

//FLOX
let fivephtoruracil_flox = 500;
let leikovorin_flox = 500;
let oxaliplatin_flox = 85;

//de Gramont
let fivephtoruracil_degramont_do = 400;
let fivephtoruracil_degramont_posle = 600;
let leikovorin_degramont = 200;

//FOLFIRI
let irinitekan_folfiri = 180;
let fivephtoruracil_folfiri_do = 400;
let fivephtoruracil_folfiri_posle = 2400;
let leikovorin_folfiri = 200;

//FOLFOX7
let fivephtoruracil_folfox7 = 2400;
let leikovorin_folfox7 = 400;
let oxaliplatin_folfox7 = 130;

//FOLFOXIRI
let fivephtoruracil_folfoxiri = 3200;
let leikovorin_folfoxiri = 200;
let oxaliplatin_folfoxiri = 185;
let irinitekan_folfoxiri = 165;

//XELIRI
let irinitekan_xeliri = 250;
let kapecitabin_xeliri = 1000;

//IROX
let oxaliplatin_irox = 85;
let irinitekan_irox = 200;

//FOLFIRINOX
let oxaliplatin_folfirinox = 85;
let irinitekan_folfirinox = 180;
let fivephtoruracil_folfirinox_do = 400;
let fivephtoruracil_folfirinox_posle = 2400;
let leikovorin_folfirinox = 400;

//GEM-CAP
let gemcitabin_gemcap = 1000;
let kapecitabin_gemcap = 650;


let button = document.querySelector('#submit');
button.onclick = function func(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Предотвращение стандартного поведения
    let exampleInputrost = Number(document.getElementById("exampleInputrost").value);
    let exampleInputves = Number(document.getElementById("exampleInputves").value);
    let exampleInputshema = document.getElementById("exampleInputshema").value.toUpperCase();
    function square_body_chemotherapy(exampleInputrost, exampleInputves) {
    let weitfloatsquare = Math.pow(exampleInputrost, 0.5);
    let heightfloatsquare = Math.pow(exampleInputves, 0.5);
    let square_body = 0.0167 * weitfloatsquare * heightfloatsquare;
    return square_body.toFixed(1);
  }
    let res = square_body_chemotherapy(exampleInputrost, exampleInputves);
    if (exampleInputshema == "TPF") {
        let docetaxel_doza = docetaxel * res;
        let cisplatin_doza = cisplatin * res;
        let fivephtoruracil_doza = fivephtoruracil * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза доцетаксела: ' + Math.round(docetaxel_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза цисплатина: ' + Math.round(cisplatin_doza) + ' мг. в/в в течение 24 часов в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза 5-фторурацила: ' + Math.round(fivephtoruracil_doza) + ' мг. в сутки в/в в виде постоянной инфузии с 1 по 4 день.</p><p>Каждый 21 день.</p>';
    } else if (exampleInputshema == "TIP") {
        let paklitaxel_doza = paklitaxel * res;
        let iphosfamid_doza = iphosfamid * res; 
        let mesna_tip_doza_do = mesna_tip_do * res;
        let mesna_tip_doza_posle = mesna_tip_posle * res;
        let cisplatina_doza = cisplatina * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза паклитаксела: ' + Math.round(paklitaxel_doza) + ' мг. в течение 3 часов в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза ифосфамида: ' + Math.round(iphosfamid_doza) + ' мг. в сутки в/в в течение 2 часов с 1 по 3 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза месны: ' + Math.round(mesna_tip_doza_do) + ' мг. в/в до ифосфамида и ' + Math.round(mesna_tip_doza_posle) + ' мг. в/в через 4-8 часов после ифосфамида в 1-3 дни.</p>' + '<p>Доза цисплатина: ' + Math.round(cisplatina_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p><p>Каждые 21-28 дни.</p>';
    } else if (exampleInputshema == "TIC") {
        let paklitaxel_doza = paklitaxel_tic * res;
        let iphosfamid_doza = iphosfamid_tic * res; 
        let mesna_tic_doza_do = mesna_tic_do * res;
        let mesna_tic_doza_posle = mesna_tic_posle * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза паклитаксела: ' + Math.round(paklitaxel_doza) + ' мг. в течение 3 часов в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза ифосфамида: ' + Math.round(iphosfamid_doza) + ' мг. в/в с 1 по 3 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза месны: ' + Math.round(mesna_tic_doza_do) + ' мг. в/в до ифосфамида и ' + Math.round(mesna_tic_doza_posle) + ' мг. в/в через 4-8 часов после ифосфамида в 1-3 дни.</p>' + '<p>Доза карбоплатина: AUC 6 в/в в 1 день.</p><p>Каждые 21-28 дни.</p>';
    } else if (exampleInputshema == "EP") {
        let cisplatin_ep_doza = cisplatin_ep * res;
        let etopozid_ep_doza = etopozid_ep * res; 
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза цисплатина: ' + Math.round(cisplatin_ep_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза этопозида: ' + Math.round(etopozid_ep_doza) + ' мг. в/в с 1 по 3 день.</p>' + '<p>Каждые 3 недели.</p>';
    } else if (exampleInputshema == "EC") {
        let etopozid_ec_doza = etopozid_ec * res; 
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза карбоплатина: AUC 6 в 1 день</p>' + '<p>Доза этопозида: ' + Math.round(etopozid_ec_doza) + ' мг. в/в с 1 по 3 день.</p>' + '<p>Каждые 4 недели.</p>';
    } else if (exampleInputshema == "CAV") {
        let ciklofosfamid_cav_doza = ciklofosfamid_cav * res;
        let doxorubicin_cav_doza = doxorubicin_cav * res; 
        let vinkristin_cav_doza = vinkristin_cav * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза циклофосфамида: ' + Math.round(ciklofosfamid_cav_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза доксорубицина: ' + Math.round(doxorubicin_cav_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза винкристина: ' + Math.round(vinkristin_cav_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Каждые 3 недели.</p>';
    } else if (exampleInputshema == "CAE") {
        let ciklofosfamid_cae_doza = ciklofosfamid_cae * res;
        let doxorubicin_cae_doza = doxorubicin_cae * res; 
        let etopozid_cae_doza = etopozid_cae * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза циклофосфамида: ' + Math.round(ciklofosfamid_cae_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза доксорубицина: ' + Math.round(doxorubicin_cae_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза этопозида: ' + Math.round(etopozid_cae_doza) + ' мг. в/в с 1 по 5 день.</p>' + '<p>Каждые 3 недели.</p>';
    } else if (exampleInputshema == "ECF") {
        let epirubicin_ecf_doza = epirubicin_ecf * res;
        let cisplatin_ecf_doza = cisplatin_ecf * res; 
        let fivephtoruracil_ecf_doza = fivephtoruracil_ecf * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза эпирубицина: ' + Math.round(epirubicin_ecf_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза цисплатина: ' + Math.round(cisplatin_ecf_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза 5-фторурацила: ' + Math.round(fivephtoruracil_ecf_doza) + ' мг. в день в виде постоянной инфузии с 1 по 21 день.</p>' + '<p>Каждые 3 недели.</p>';
    } else if (exampleInputshema == "EOF") {
        let epirubicin_eof_doza = epirubicin_eof * res;
        let oxaliplatin_eof_doza = oxaliplatin_eof * res; 
        let fivephtoruracil_eof_doza = fivephtoruracil_eof * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза эпирубицина: ' + Math.round(epirubicin_eof_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза оксалиплатина: ' + Math.round(oxaliplatin_eof_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза 5-фторурацила: ' + Math.round(fivephtoruracil_eof_doza) + ' мг. в день в виде постоянной инфузии с 1 по 21 день.</p>' + '<p>Каждые 3 недели.</p>';
    } else if (exampleInputshema == "EOX") {
        let epirubicin_eox_doza = epirubicin_eox * res;
        let oxaliplatin_eox_doza = oxaliplatin_eox * res; 
        let kapecitabin_eox_doza = kapecitabin_eox * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза эпирубицина: ' + Math.round(epirubicin_eox_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза оксалиплатина: ' + Math.round(oxaliplatin_eox_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза капецитабина: ' + Math.round(kapecitabin_eox_doza) + ' мг. p.o. 2 р в день постоянно.</p>' + '<p>Каждые 3 недели.</p>';
    } else if (exampleInputshema == "ECX") {
        let epirubicin_ecx_doza = epirubicin_ecx * res;
        let cisplatin_ecx_doza = cisplatin_ecx * res; 
        let kapecitabin_ecx_doza = kapecitabin_ecx * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза эпирубицина: ' + Math.round(epirubicin_ecx_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза цисплатина: ' + Math.round(cisplatin_ecx_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза капецитабина: ' + Math.round(kapecitabin_ecx_doza) + ' мг. p.o. 2 р в день постоянно.</p>' + '<p>Каждые 3 недели.</p>';
    } else if (exampleInputshema == "XELOX") {
        let oxaliplatin_xelox_doza = oxaliplatin_xelox * res; 
        let kapecitabin_xelox_doza = kapecitabin_xelox * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза оксалиплатина: ' + Math.round(oxaliplatin_xelox_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза капецитабина: ' + Math.round(kapecitabin_xelox_doza) + ' мг. p.o. 2 р в день с 1 по 14 день.</p>' + '<p>Каждые 3 недели.</p>';
    } else if (exampleInputshema == "DCF") {
        let docetaksel_dcf_doza = docetaksel_dcf * res;
        let cisplatin_dcf_doza = cisplatin_dcf * res; 
        let fivephtoruracil_dcf_doza = fivephtoruracil_dcf * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза доцетаксела: ' + Math.round(docetaksel_dcf_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза цисплатина: ' + Math.round(cisplatin_dcf_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза 5-фторурацила: ' + Math.round(fivephtoruracil_dcf_doza) + ' мг. в день в виде постоянной инфузии с 1 по 5 день.</p>' + '<p>Каждые 3 недели.</p>';
    } else if (exampleInputshema == "CF") {
        let cisplatin_cf_doza = cisplatin_cf * res; 
        let fivephtoruracil_cf_doza = fivephtoruracil_cf * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза цисплатина: ' + Math.round(cisplatin_cf_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза 5-фторурацила: ' + Math.round(fivephtoruracil_cf_doza) + ' мг. в день в виде постоянной инфузии с 1 по 5 день.</p>' + '<p>Каждые 28 дней.</p>';
    } else if (exampleInputshema == "MAYO" || exampleInputshema == "MAYO CLINIC") {
        let fivephtoruracil_mayo_doza = fivephtoruracil_mayo * res; 
        let leikovorin_mayo_doza = leikovorin_mayo * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза 5-фторурацила: ' + Math.round(fivephtoruracil_mayo_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 - 5 дни.</p>' + '<p>Доза лейковорина: ' + Math.round(leikovorin_mayo_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1-5 дни, вводится до 5-фторурацила.</p>' + '<p>Каждые 4-5 недель.</p>';
    } else if (exampleInputshema == "ROSWELL" || exampleInputshema == "ROSWELL PARK") {
        let fivephtoruracil_roswell_doza = fivephtoruracil_roswell * res; 
        let leikovorin_roswell_doza = leikovorin_roswell * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза 5-фторурацила: ' + Math.round(fivephtoruracil_roswell_doza) + ' мг. еженедельно в течение 6 недель.</p>' + '<p>Доза лейковорина: ' + Math.round(leikovorin_roswell_doza) + ' мг. в/в в течение 2 часов еженедельно до введения 5-фторурацила в течение 6 недель.</p>' + '<p>Каждые 8 недель.</p>';
    } else if (exampleInputshema == "FOLFOX4" || exampleInputshema == "FOLFOX 4") {
        let fivephtoruracil_folfox4_do_doza = fivephtoruracil_folfox4_do * res;
        let fivephtoruracil_folfox4_posle_doza = fivephtoruracil_folfox4_posle * res; 
        let leikovorin_folfox4_doza = leikovorin_folfox4 * res;
        let oxaliplatin_folfox4_doza = oxaliplatin_folfox4 * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза оксалиплатина: ' + Math.round(oxaliplatin_folfox4_doza) + ' мг. в/в в течение 2 часов в 1 день (одновременно с лейковорином).</p>' + '<p>Доза лейковорина: ' + Math.round(leikovorin_folfox4_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 и 2 день в виде 2-х часовой инфузии до введения 5-фторурацила.</p>' + '<p>Доза 5-фторурацила: ' + Math.round(fivephtoruracil_folfox4_do_doza) + ' мг. в/в болюсно, далее ' + Math.round(fivephtoruracil_folfox4_posle_doza) + ' мг. в виде постоянной в/в инфузии в течение 22 часов в 1 и 2 день.</p>' + '<p>Каждые 2 недели.</p>';
    } else if (exampleInputshema == "FOLFOX6" || exampleInputshema == "FOLFOX 6") {
        let fivephtoruracil_folfox6_do_doza = fivephtoruracil_folfox6_do * res;
        let fivephtoruracil_folfox6_posle_doza = fivephtoruracil_folfox6_posle * res; 
        let leikovorin_folfox6_doza = leikovorin_folfox6 * res;
        let oxaliplatin_folfox6_doza = oxaliplatin_folfox6 * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза оксалиплатина: ' + Math.round(oxaliplatin_folfox6_doza) + ' мг. в/в до 5-фторурацила и лейковорин в 1, 15 и 29 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза лейковорина: ' + Math.round(leikovorin_folfox6_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 и 2 день в виде 2-х часовой инфузии до введения 5-фторурацила.</p>' + '<p>Доза 5-фторурацила: ' + Math.round(fivephtoruracil_folfox6_do_doza) + ' мг. в/в болюсно в 1 день, далее ' + Math.round(fivephtoruracil_folfox6_posle_doza) + ' мг. в виде постоянной в/в инфузии в течение 46 часов.</p>' + '<p>Каждые 2 недели.</p>';
    } else if (exampleInputshema == "MFOLFOX7" || exampleInputshema == "MFOLFOX 7") {
        let fivephtoruracil_mfolfox7_doza = fivephtoruracil_mfolfox7 * res; 
        let leikovorin_mfolfox7_doza = leikovorin_mfolfox7 * res;
        let oxaliplatin_mfolfox7_doza = oxaliplatin_mfolfox7 * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза оксалиплатина: ' + Math.round(oxaliplatin_mfolfox7_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза лейковорина: ' + Math.round(leikovorin_mfolfox7_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день в виде 2-х часовой инфузии до введения 5-фторурацила.</p>' + '<p>Доза 5-фторурацила: ' + Math.round(fivephtoruracil_mfolfox7_doza) + ' мг. в виде постоянной в/в инфузии в течение 46 часов (1-2 день).</p>' + '<p>Каждые 2 недели.</p>';
    } else if (exampleInputshema == "FLOX") {
        let fivephtoruracil_flox_doza = fivephtoruracil_flox * res; 
        let leikovorin_flox_doza = leikovorin_flox * res;
        let oxaliplatin_flox_doza = oxaliplatin_flox * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза оксалиплатина: ' + Math.round(oxaliplatin_flox_doza) + ' мг. в/в до 5-фторурацила и лейковорина в 1, 15 и 29 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза лейковорина: ' + Math.round(leikovorin_flox_doza) + ' мг. в/в в течение 2 часов еженедельно в течение 6 недель.</p>' + '<p>Доза 5-фторурацила: ' + Math.round(fivephtoruracil_flox_doza) + ' мг. в/в еженедельно в течение 6 недель, вводится через 1 час после начала инфузии лейковорина.</p>' + '<p>Каждые 8 недель.</p>';
    } else if (exampleInputshema == "DEGRAMONT" || exampleInputshema == "DE GRAMONT") {
        let fivephtoruracil_degramont_do_doza = fivephtoruracil_degramont_do * res;
        let fivephtoruracil_degramont_posle_doza = fivephtoruracil_degramont_posle * res; 
        let leikovorin_degramont_doza = leikovorin_degramont * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза 5-фторурацила: ' + Math.round(fivephtoruracil_degramont_do_doza) + ' мг. в/в болюсно, далее ' + Math.round(fivephtoruracil_degramont_posle_doza) + ' мг. в виде постоянной в/в инфузии в течение 22 часов в 1 и 2 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза лейковорина: ' + Math.round(leikovorin_degramont_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 и 2 день в виде 2-х часовой инфузии до введения 5-фторурацила.</p>' + '<p>Каждые 2 недели.</p>';
    } else if (exampleInputshema == "FOLFIRI") {
        let fivephtoruracil_folfiri_do_doza = fivephtoruracil_folfiri_do * res;
        let fivephtoruracil_folfiri_posle_doza = fivephtoruracil_folfiri_posle * res; 
        let leikovorin_folfiri_doza = leikovorin_folfiri * res;
        let irinitekan_folfiri_doza = irinitekan_folfiri * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза иринотекана: ' + Math.round(irinitekan_folfiri_doza) + ' мг. в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза лейковорина: ' + Math.round(leikovorin_folfiri_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день в виде 2-х часовой инфузии до введения 5-фторурацила.</p>' + '<p>Доза 5-фторурацила: ' + Math.round(fivephtoruracil_folfiri_do_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день, далее ' + Math.round(fivephtoruracil_folfiri_posle_doza) + ' мг. в виде постоянной в/в инфузии в течение 46 часов.</p>' + '<p>Каждые 2 недели.</p>';
    } else if (exampleInputshema == "FOLFOX7" || exampleInputshema == "FOLFOX 7") {
        let fivephtoruracil_folfox7_doza = fivephtoruracil_folfox7 * res; 
        let leikovorin_folfox7_doza = leikovorin_folfox7 * res;
        let oxaliplatin_folfox7_doza = oxaliplatin_folfox7 * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза оксалиплатина: ' + Math.round(oxaliplatin_folfox7_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза лейковорина: ' + Math.round(leikovorin_folfox7_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день в виде 2-х часовой инфузии до введения 5-фторурацила.</p>' + '<p>Доза 5-фторурацила: ' + Math.round(fivephtoruracil_folfox7_doza) + ' мг. в виде постоянной в/в инфузии в течение 46 часов (1-2 день).</p>' + '<p>Каждые 2 недели.</p>';
    }  else if (exampleInputshema == "FOLFOXIRI") {
        let fivephtoruracil_folfoxiri_doza = fivephtoruracil_folfoxiri * res; 
        let leikovorin_folfoxiri_doza = leikovorin_folfoxiri * res;
        let oxaliplatin_folfoxiri_doza = oxaliplatin_folfoxiri * res;
        let irinitekan_folfoxiri_doza = irinitekan_folfoxiri * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза иринотекана: ' + Math.round(irinitekan_folfoxiri_doza) + ' мг. в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза оксалиплатина: ' + Math.round(oxaliplatin_folfoxiri_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза лейковорина: ' + Math.round(leikovorin_folfoxiri_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день в виде 2-х часовой инфузии до введения 5-фторурацила.</p>' + '<p>Доза 5-фторурацила: ' + Math.round(fivephtoruracil_folfoxiri_doza) + ' мг. в виде постоянной в/в инфузии в течение 46 часов (1-2 день).</p>' + '<p>Каждые 2 недели.</p>';
    } else if (exampleInputshema == "XELIRI") {
        let irinitekan_xeliri_doza = irinitekan_xeliri * res; 
        let kapecitabin_xeliri_doza = kapecitabin_xeliri * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза иринотекана: ' + Math.round(irinitekan_xeliri_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза капецитабина: ' + Math.round(kapecitabin_xeliri_doza) + ' мг. p.o. 2 р в день с 1 по 14 день.</p>' + '<p>Каждые 3 недели.</p>';
    } else if (exampleInputshema == "IROX") {
        let oxaliplatin_irox_doza = oxaliplatin_irox * res; 
        let irinitekan_irox_doza = irinitekan_irox * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза иринотекана: ' + Math.round(irinitekan_irox_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза оксалиплатина: ' + Math.round(oxaliplatin_irox_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Каждые 3 недели.</p>';
    }  else if (exampleInputshema == "FOLFIRINOX") {
        let fivephtoruracil_folfirinox_do_doza = fivephtoruracil_folfirinox_do * res; 
        let fivephtoruracil_folfirinox_posle_doza = fivephtoruracil_folfirinox_posle * res;
        let leikovorin_folfirinox_doza = leikovorin_folfirinox * res;
        let oxaliplatin_folfirinox_doza = oxaliplatin_folfirinox * res;
        let irinitekan_folfirinox_doza = irinitekan_folfirinox * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза иринотекана: ' + Math.round(irinitekan_folfirinox_doza) + ' мг. в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза оксалиплатина: ' + Math.round(oxaliplatin_folfirinox_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза лейковорина: ' + Math.round(leikovorin_folfirinox_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза 5-фторурацила: ' + Math.round(fivephtoruracil_folfirinox_do_doza) + ' мг. в/в в 1 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза 5-фторурацила: ' + Math.round(fivephtoruracil_folfirinox_posle_doza) + ' мг. в виде постоянной в/в инфузии в течение 46 часов (1-2 день).</p>' + '<p>Каждые 2 недели.</p>';
    }  else if (exampleInputshema == "GEM-CAP" || exampleInputshema == "GEMCAP" || exampleInputshema == "GEM - CAP") {
        let gemcitabin_gemcap_doza = gemcitabin_gemcap * res; 
        let kapecitabin_gemcap_doza = kapecitabin_gemcap * res;
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = '<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + res + ' кв. м.</p>' + '<p>Доза гемцитабина: ' + Math.round(gemcitabin_gemcap_doza) + ' мг. в 1 и 8 день.</p>' + '<p>Доза капецитабина: ' + Math.round(kapecitabin_gemcap_doza) + ' мг. р.о. 2 раза в день с 1 по 14 день.</p>' + '<p>Каждые 3 недели.</p>';
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Код сейчас максимально упрощен) его можно сократить, усложнив при этом) с помощью массивов например

Comment: А можете показать как?

Comment: в коде 318 строк, вы действительно хотите чтоб я потратил на это 2-3 часа жизни?) Составьте массив.. например.. `epirubicin_eof_doza` состоит из epirubicin и eof и тд) сгруппируйте и пройдитесь циклом, с учетом что от чего зависит) + тут отсутствует html часть, даже тестировать  не выйдет) врятле вам кто поможет с этой задачей

Comment: Возможно будет правильней переписать `if else` на `switch`. И присваивать для `document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML` вне блока, записывать текст в переменную. Для вставки переменных в текст наверное проще будет делать через шаблоны строк (`).

Answer (score 5):

Не создавайте большое кол-во переменных, особенно связанных между собой. Их можно объединить в единый объект.

Так все переменные, связанные со схемой, можно занести в объект, например `Schema`. Для каждой схемы так же можно создать функцию `template`, которая будет возвращать шаблон с результатом рассчетов.

Я не стал добавлять шаблоны для каждой схемы, добавил только для первой, второй и последней. Пояснения по некторым моментам в комментариях в коде. Этот код еще можно улучшить, но я оставлю это вам.

```js
const masks = {
  digits: new RegExp(/[^0-9]/g),
  cyrillic: new RegExp(/[а-яА-ЯёЁ]/g),
};

// Объект со всеми интерактивными элементами
const DOMElements = {
  inputs: { // все инпуты
    exampleSchema: {
      nativeElement: document.querySelector('#exampleInputshema'),
      mask: masks.cyrillic,
      get value() {
        return this.nativeElement.value;
      },
    },
    exampleGrowth: {
      nativeElement: document.querySelector('#exampleInputrost'),
      mask: masks.digits,
      get value() { // аксессор get для быстрого досупа к преобразованному в number значению value инпута
        return +this.nativeElement.value;
      },
    },
    exampleWeight: {
      nativeElement: document.querySelector('#exampleInputves'),
      mask: masks.digits,
      get value() {
        return +this.nativeElement.value;
      },
    },
  },
  submit: document.querySelector('#submit'),
  elem: {
    nativeElement: document.getElementById('elem'),
    clear: function () { // функция удаления всех дочерних элементов из elem
      this.nativeElement.childNodes.forEach((node) => node.remove());
    },
  },
};

/**
* Создает блок div с p внутри из массива строк
*/
function createTemplate(items) {
  items = items.map((str) => { // переводим строки в элементы p
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    p.textContent = str;
    return p;
  });
  const container = document.createElement('div'); // создаем контейнер div(не обязательно)
  container.append(...items); // добавляем элементы p в div
  return container; // возвращаем контейнер
}

/**
* Функция рассчета дозировки
* Принимает в себя объект схемы и площадь тела
* Возвращает объект с дозировками
*/
function calculateDose(schema, body) {
  const entries = Object.entries(schema);
  const dose = {};
  for (let prop of entries) { // проходим по объекту схемы
    if (typeof prop[1] != 'number') continue; // если тип значения не number идем дальше
    dose[prop[0]] = Math.round(prop[1] * body);
  }
  return dose;
}

// Объект со схемами
const Schema = {
  TPF: { // ключ свойства объекта - это название схемы
    docetaxel: 75,
    cisplatin: 100,
    fivephtoruracil: 1000,
    template: function (body) { // функция шаблона
      const dose = calculateDose(this, body); // рассчет дозировки this - указатель на контекст, здесь this - это Schema.TPF
      const items = [
        `Площадь поверхности тела: ${body} кв. м.`,
        `Доза доцетаксела: ${dose.docetaxel} мг. в/в в 1 день.`,
        `Доза цисплатина: ${dose.cisplatin} мг. в/в в течение 24 часов в 1 день.`,
        `Доза 5-фторурацила: ${dose.fivephtoruracil} мг. в сутки в/в в виде постоянной инфузии с 1 по 4 день.`,
        `Каждый 21 день.`,
      ];
      return createTemplate(items); // возвращает шаблон с результатом
    },
  },
  TIP: {
    paklitaxel: 175,
    iphosfamid: 1000,
    mesna_before: 400,
    mesna_after: 200,
    cisplatina: 60,
    template: function (body) {
      const dose = calculateDose(this, body); // здесь this - это Schema.TIP
      const items = [
        `Площадь поверхности тела: ${body} кв. м.`,
        `Доза паклитаксела: ${dose.paklitaxel} мг. в течение 3 часов в 1 день.`,
        `Доза ифосфамида: ${dose.iphosfamid} мг. в сутки в/в в течение 2 часов с 1 по 3 день.`,
        `Доза месны: ${this.mesna_before} мг. в/в до ифосфамида и ${this.mesna_after} мг. в/в через 4-8 часов после ифосфамида в 1-3 дни.`,
        `Доза цисплатина: ${dose.cisplatina} мг. в/в в 1 день.`,
        `Каждые 21-28 дни.`,
      ];
      return createTemplate(items);
    },
  },
  TIC: {
    paklitaxel: 175,
    iphosfamid: 1000,
    mesna_tip_before: 400,
    mesna_tip_after: 200,
    cisplatina: 60,
  },
  EP: {
    cisplatin: 80,
    etopozid: 80,
  },
  EC: {
    etopozid: 100,
  },
  CAV: {
    ciklofosfamid: 1000,
    doxorubicin: 40,
    vinkristin: 1.4,
  },
  CAE: {
    ciklofosfamid: 1000,
    doxorubicin: 40,
    etopozid: 50,
  },
  ECF: {
    epirubicin: 50,
    cisplatin: 60,
    fivephtoruracil: 200,
  },
  EOF: {
    epirubicin: 50,
    iplatin: 130,
    fivephtoruracil: 200,
  },
  EOX: {
    epirubicin: 50,
    oxaliplatin: 130,
    kapecitabin: 625,
  },
  ECX: {
    epirubicin: 50,
    cisplatin: 60,
    kapecitabin: 625,
  },
  XELOX: {
    oxaliplatin: 130,
    kapecitabin: 1000,
  },
  DCF: {
    docetaksel: 75,
    cisplatin: 75,
    fivephtoruracil: 750,
  },
  CF: {
    cisplatin: 100,
    fivephtoruracil: 1000,
  },
  MAYO: {
    fivephtoruracil: 425,
    leikovorin: 20,
  },
  ROSWELL: {
    fivephtoruracil: 500,
    leikovorin: 500,
  },
  FOLFOX4: {
    acceptable: ['FOLFOX 4'],
    fivephtoruracil_before: 400,
    fivephtoruracil_after: 600,
    leikovorin: 200,
    oxaliplatin: 85,
  },
  FOLFOX6: {
    acceptable: ['FOLFOX 6'],
    fivephtoruracil_before: 400,
    fivephtoruracil_after: 2400,
    leikovorin: 400,
    oxaliplatin: 85,
  },
  MFOLFOX7: {
    acceptable: ['MFOLFOX 7'],
    fivephtoruracil: 3000,
    leikovorin: 200,
    oxaliplatin: 100,
  },
  FLOX: {
    fivephtoruracil: 500,
    leikovorin: 500,
    oxaliplatin: 85,
  },
  DEGRAMONT: {
    acceptable: ['DE GRAMONT'],
    fivephtoruracil_before: 400,
    fivephtoruracil_after: 600,
    leikovorin: 200,
  },
  FOLFIRI: {
    irinitekan: 180,
    fivephtoruracil_before: 400,
    fivephtoruracil_after: 2400,
    leikovorin: 200,
  },
  FOLFOX7: {
    acceptable: ['FOLFOX 7'],
    fivephtoruracil: 2400,
    leikovorin: 400,
    oxaliplatin: 130,
  },
  FOLFOXIRI: {
    fivephtoruracil: 3200,
    leikovorin: 200,
    oxaliplatin: 185,
    irinitekan: 165,
  },
  XELIRI: {
    irinitekan: 250,
    kapecitabin: 1000,
  },
  IROX: {
    oxaliplatin: 85,
    irinitekan: 200,
  },
  FOLFIRINOX: {
    oxaliplatin: 85,
    irinitekan: 180,
    fivephtoruracil_before: 400,
    fivephtoruracil_after: 2400,
    leikovorin: 400,
  },
  GEMCAP: {
    acceptable: ['GEM-CAP', 'GEM - CAP'], // массив с допустимыми значениями exampleSchema.value
    gemcitabin: 1000,
    kapecitabin: 650,
    template: function (body) {
      const dose = calculateDose(this, body);
      const items = [
        `Площадь поверхности тела: ${body} кв. м.`,
        `Доза гемцитабина: ${dose.gemcitabin} мг. в 1 и 8 день.`,
        `Доза капецитабина: ${dose.kapecitabin} мг. р.о. 2 раза в день с 1 по 14 день.`,
        `Каждые 3 недели.`,
      ];
      return createTemplate(items);
    },
  },
};

/**
* Добавляет слушатели к инпутам
*/
function addListenersToInputs() {
  for (const input in DOMElements.inputs) {
    DOMElements.inputs[input].nativeElement.addEventListener(
      'keyup',
      function () {
        const mask = DOMElements.inputs[input].mask;
        if (!mask.test(this.value)) return;
        this.value = this.value.replace(mask, '');
      }
    );
  }
}

/**
* Общая функция рассчета с выводом результата
*/
function calculate() {
  function squareBodyChemotherapy(exampleGrowth, exampleWeight) {
    const weitFloatSquare = Math.pow(exampleGrowth, 0.5);
    const heightFloatSquare = Math.pow(exampleWeight, 0.5);
    return (0.0167 * weitFloatSquare * heightFloatSquare).toFixed(1);
  }
  const exampleSchema = DOMElements.inputs.exampleSchema.value;

  const res = squareBodyChemotherapy(
    DOMElements.inputs.exampleGrowth.value, // здесь обращение к аксессорам, а не к значению инпута
    DOMElements.inputs.exampleWeight.value
  );

  for (const schema in Schema) { // проходим по объекту со схемами
    if (
      schema !== exampleSchema &&
      !Schema[schema].acceptable?.includes(exampleSchema) // если ключ схемы не равен значению инпута exampleSchema и массив acceptable не содержит в себе значение инпута exampleSchema, идем дальше
    )
      continue;
    DOMElements.elem.clear();
    DOMElements.elem.nativeElement.append(Schema[schema].template(res)); // добавляем контейнер шаблона с результатом в elem
    break; // выходим из цикла
  }
}

addListenersToInputs();

DOMElements.submit.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  calculate();
});
```

```html
<div class="form-control">
  <label for="schema">Schema</label>
  <input name="schema" type="text" id="exampleInputshema" value="TPF" />
</div>
<div class="form-control">
  <label for="growth">Growth</label>
  <input name="growth" type="text" id="exampleInputrost" value="123" />
</div>
<div class="form-control">
  <label for="weight">Weight</label>
  <input name="weight" type="text" id="exampleInputves" value="33" />
</div>
<div class="form-control">
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>

<div id="elem"></div>
```

#### UPD

Можете посмотреть вариант еще получше, он более соответствует [паттерну DRY](https://web-creator.ru/articles/dry):

```js
const masks = {
  digits: new RegExp(/[^0-9]/g),
  cyrillic: new RegExp(/[а-яА-ЯёЁ]/g),
};

const DOMElements = {
  inputs: ((inputs) => {
    return inputs.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      const [id, mask, type] = curr;
      acc[id] = {
        nativeElement: document.getElementById(id),
        mask,
        get value() {
          return new type(this.nativeElement.value).valueOf();
        },
      };
      acc[id].nativeElement.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
        if (!mask.test(this.value)) return;
        this.value = this.value.replace(mask, '');
      });
      return acc;
    }, {});
  })([
    ['exampleSchema', masks.cyrillic, String],
    ['exampleWeight', masks.digits, Number],
    ['exampleGrowth', masks.digits, Number],
  ]),
  submit: document.querySelector('#submit'),
  elem: {
    nativeElement: document.getElementById('elem'),
    clear: function () {
      // манкипатчинг?
      while (this.nativeElement.firstChild)
        this.nativeElement.lastChild.remove();
    },
  },
};

function appendTemplate(schema, body) {
  const doses = calculateDose(schema, body);
  let items = [
    `${schema.interval}.`,
    `Площадь поверхности тела: ${body} кв. м.`,
  ];
  for (const dose in doses) {
    const schemeTranslation = translateScheme(dose);
    const period = !doses[dose].period
      ? `${doses[dose].before.value} м.г. ${doses[dose].before.period} и ${doses[dose].before.value} м.г. ${doses[dose].after.period}`
      : doses[dose].period;
    items.splice(
      1,
      0,
      `Доза ${schemeTranslation}: ${
        doses[dose].value ? doses[dose].value + ' мг.' : ''
      } ${period}.`
    );
  }
  items = items
    .map((str) => {
      const p = document.createElement('p');
      p.textContent = str;
      return p;
    })
    .reverse();
  DOMElements.elem.nativeElement.append(...items);
}

function calculateDose(schema, body) {
  const entries = Object.entries(schema);
  const dose = {};
  for (let prop of entries) {
    if (typeof prop[1]?.value != 'number' && !prop[1].after && !prop[1].before)
      continue;
    const res = Math.round(prop[1].value * body);
    if (res) {
      dose[prop[0]] = {
        value: res,
        period: prop[1].period,
      };
      continue;
    }
    dose[prop[0]] = prop[1];
  }
  return dose;
}

function translateScheme(key) {
  const translations = {
    docetaxel: 'доцетаксел',
    cisplatin: 'циспластин',
    fivephtoruracil: '5-фторурацил',
    paklitaxel: 'паклитаксел',
    iphosfamid: 'ифосфамид',
    mesna: 'месна',
    kapecitabin: 'капецитабин',
    gemcitabin: 'гемцитабин',
  };
  if (!translations[key]) throw `Ключа "${key}" не существует`;
  return translations[key];
}

const Schema = {
  TPF: {
    docetaxel: {
      value: 75,
      period: 'в/в в 1 день',
    },
    cisplatin: {
      value: 100,
      period: 'в/в в течение 24 часов в 1 день',
    },
    fivephtoruracil: {
      value: 1000,
      period: 'в сутки в/в в виде постоянной инфузии с 1 по 4 день',
    },
    interval: 'Каждый 21 день',
  },
  TIP: {
    paklitaxel: {
      value: 175,
      period: 'в течение 3 часов в 1 день',
    },
    iphosfamid: {
      value: 1000,
      period: 'в сутки в/в в течение 2 часов с 1 по 3 день.',
    },
    mesna: {
      before: {
        value: 400,
        period: 'в/в до ифосфамида',
      },
      after: {
        value: 200,
        period: 'в/в через 4-8 часов после ифосфамида в 1-3 дни',
      },
    },
    cisplatin: {
      value: 60,
      period: 'в/в в 1 день.',
    },
    interval: 'Каждые 21-28 дни',
  },
  GEMCAP: {
    acceptable: ['GEM-CAP', 'GEM - CAP'],
    gemcitabin: {
      value: 1000,
      period: 'в 1 и 8 день',
    },
    kapecitabin: {
      value: 650,
      period: 'р.о. 2 раза в день с 1 по 14 день',
    },
    interval: 'Каждые 3 недели',
  },
};

function calculate() {
  function squareBodyChemotherapy(exampleGrowth, exampleWeight) {
    const weitFloatSquare = Math.pow(exampleGrowth, 0.5);
    const heightFloatSquare = Math.pow(exampleWeight, 0.5);
    return (0.0167 * weitFloatSquare * heightFloatSquare).toFixed(1);
  }
  const exampleSchema = DOMElements.inputs.exampleSchema.value;

  const body = squareBodyChemotherapy(
    DOMElements.inputs.exampleGrowth.value,
    DOMElements.inputs.exampleWeight.value
  );

  for (const schema in Schema) {
    if (
      schema !== exampleSchema &&
      !Schema[schema].acceptable?.includes(exampleSchema)
    )
      continue;
    DOMElements.elem.clear();
    appendTemplate(Schema[schema], body);
    break;
  }
}

DOMElements.submit.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  calculate();
});
```

```html
<div class="form-control">
  <label for="schema">Schema</label>
  <input name="schema" type="text" id="exampleSchema" value="TIP" />
</div>
<div class="form-control">
  <label for="growth">Growth</label>
  <input name="growth" type="text" id="exampleGrowth" value="123" />
</div>
<div class="form-control">
  <label for="weight">Weight</label>
  <input name="weight" type="text" id="exampleWeight" value="33" />
</div>
<div class="form-control">
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>

<div id="elem"></div>
```

Изменениям подверглись в основном функции сборки шаблона. Если будут вопросы, задавайте.

Почитайте вот это, будет полезно:

- [Циклы while и for](https://learn.javascript.ru/while-for)
- [Объекты](https://learn.javascript.ru/object)
- [Методы объекта, "this"](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-methods)
- [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/IIFE)
- [Тернарный оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: А вы не из ленивых, лайк за автора :) Если не секрет, сколько по времени заняло ответ на этот вопрос? Разобраться в коде + сам код + написать его сюда

Comment: @Jour не засекал, может 40-60 минут на все про все.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду разбираться.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x={
    // 1 не стесняйтесь проксировать часто используемые функции, объекты и методы. пальцы скажут вам спасибо
    GI: function(id) {return document.getElementById(id)},
    GQS: function(qs) {return document.querySelector(qs)},

    // 2 не используйте несколько почти идентичных функций там где можно сделать одну универсальную
    // 3 выделять под регулярные шаблоны, отдельные переменные незачем ибо кроме этой функции они нигде не используются
    reg: function(id) {if (this.GI(id).value.search(reg) !=  -1)
        this.GI(id).value  =  this.GI(id).value.replace((id=='exampleInputshema' ? /[а-яА-ЯёЁ]/g : /[^0-9]/g), '');},
    // да и вообще, используя select вместо ручного ввода, можно избавиться от нужды щупать значения регуляркой.

    /* пока отложим ширево с его коэфицентами в сторонку, ибо код и так пока что штырит знатно =)
    соберём универсальный вывод рецепта и все с ним связаное */
    body: function(){return (0.0167 * Math.pow(this.GI('exampleInputrost').value, 0.5) * Math.pow(this.GI('exampleInputves').value, 0.5)).toFixed(1);},
    sbc: function() {
    let weitfloatsquare = Math.pow(this.GI('exampleInputrost').value, 0.5);
    let heightfloatsquare = Math.pow(this.GI('exampleInputves').value, 0.5);
    let square_body = 0.0167 * weitfloatsquare * heightfloatsquare;
    return square_body.toFixed(1);
  },
    out: function(scheme)
        {
            this.GI('elem').innerHTML='<p>Площадь поверхности тела: ' + this.sbc() + ' кв. м.</p>';
            /* теперь дробим рецепт любого препарата на составляющие и уже исходя из этого будем формировать объект с коэфицентами вынося все лишнее туда */
            /* <p>Доза name: doze мг inject_type(что то не заметил, был ли хоть 1 не в\в?) intervals.</p> i++ */
            /* соответственно массив\объект препарата будет выглядеть как то так [name, name_ru, doze_source(before), dose_after, inject_type, intervals]*/ /**/
            for (var f in schemes)
                {
                    if(f == scheme){
                        for(var i=0; schemes[f][i]; i++){
                            this.GI('elem').innerHTML += "<p>Доза " + schemes[f][i].name_ru + ": " + schemes[f][i].dose_source * this.sbc() + " мг " + (schemes[f][i].dose_after ? 'до, ' + (schemes[f][i].dose_after * this.sbc()) + ' после' :'') + schemes[f][i].inject_type + schemes[f][i].intervals + ".</p>";}
                        break;
                        }
                /*
                */
                }
            }
}

var schemes = {
TPF:{
    0: {
        name: 'docetaxel',
        name_ru: 'доцетаксела',
        dose_source: 75,
        dose_after: '',
        corrector: '',
        inject_type: 'в/в',
        intervals: 'в 1 день'
        },
    1: {
        name: 'cisplatin',
        name_ru: 'цисплатина',
        dose_source: 100,
        dose_after: '',
        corrector: '',
        inject_type: 'в/в',
        intervals: 'в течение 24 часов в 1 день'
        },
    2: {
        name: 'fivephtoruracil',
        name_ru: '5-фторурацила',
        dose_source: 1000,
        dose_after: '',
        corrector: '',
        inject_type: 'в/в в виде постоянной инфузии с 1 по 4 день',
        intervals: '.</p><p>Каждый 21 день'
        }
    },
TIP:{
    0: {
        name: 'paklitaxel',
        name_ru: 'паклитаксела',
        dose_source: 175,
        dose_after: '',
        corrector: '',
        inject_type: '',
        intervals: ''
        },
    1: {
        name: 'iphosfamid',
        name_ru: 'ифосфамида',
        dose_source: 1000,
        dose_after: '',
        corrector: '',
        inject_type: '',
        intervals: ''
        },
    2: {
        name: 'mesna_tip',
        name_ru: 'месны',
        dose_source: 400,
        dose_after: 200,
        corrector: '',
        inject_type: '',
        intervals: ''
        },
    3: {
        name: 'cisplatina',
        name_ru: 'цисплатина',
        dose_source: 60,
        dose_after: '',
        corrector: '',
        inject_type: '',
        intervals: ''
        }
    },
TIC:{
    0: {
        name: '',
        name_ru: '',
        dose_source: '',
        dose_after: '',
        corrector: '',
        inject_type: '',
        intervals: ''
        },
    1: {
        name: '',
        name_ru: '',
        dose_source: '',
        dose_after: '',
        corrector: '',
        inject_type: '',
        intervals: ''
        },
    2: {
        name: '',
        name_ru: '',
        dose_source: '',
        dose_after: '',
        corrector: '',
        inject_type: '',
        intervals: ''
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
<select id='exampleInputshema'>
<option>TPF</option>
<option>TIP</option>
<option>TIC</option>
</select>
<input type='number' id='exampleInputrost'/>
<input type='number' id='exampleInputves'/>
<input type='button'  onclick='x.out(x.GI("exampleInputshema").value)' value='ok'/>
</form>
<div id='elem'></div>
```

p.s. полностью вбил только первую схему(TPF), TIP вбита частично, TIC вовсе пустая, так что не удивляйтесь полупустым и пустым строкам.
уверен, остальное сами спокойно вобъете, если мой вариант устроит)